# Cannot find where end input is missing

Tags: ruby

I'm very sorry for the trivial question, i'm very new in Ruby.
It shows me

```
13-3.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'"
```

But i just can't see where i should put "end" here

```
if File.exist?(questions) && if File.exist?(answers)
    f = File.new(questions, "r:UTF-8")
    question_line = f.readlines
    f.close
    g = File.new(answers, "r:UTF-8")
    answer_line = g.readlines
    g.close

    right_answers = 0
    position = 0
    questions_amount = question_line.length

    while position <= questions_amount
        puts question_line[position]
        user_input = gets.encode("UTF-8").chomp
        if user_input == answer_line[position]
            puts "Верный ответ"
            right_answers += 1
        else
            puts "Неправильно. Верный ответ: " + answer_line[position]
        end
        position += 1
    end
    puts "У вас #{right_answers} правильных ответов из #{questions_amount}"
else
    puts "Файл не найден"
end
```

Comment: You need to strike the second `if` in your first line. That's not the answer, but is something that needs to be done.

Comment: Are you sure you have pasted all the code of the file `13-3.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot `do` in `while` statement.

```rb
while position <= questions_amount do
  # ...
end
```

Also, as mentioned in comments, the first line should be

```rb
if File.exist?(questions) && File.exist?(answers)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `do` keyword in a `while` loop is [optional](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-while+Loop).